# Arcgis javscript calculating lines in a place

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, features

I have two mapservice. Fist service includes parcels and second includes water pipe lines. I want to calculate total pipelines length in a parcel. How can I calculate this via arcgis javascript API. For example 2201 number parcel includes 284 meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this solution. But I wish to know if there is a better solution, since when I compared my results with ArcMap there are some areas which has a slight difference in the length of pipes.

```
var query = new Query();
var queryTask = new QueryTask("feature layer with pipes");
query.geometry = selectionGeometryArea;
query.returnGeometry = true;

query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_CONTAINS;
query.outFields = ["*"];

queryTask.execute(query, function (results) {
   var lengthParams = new LengthsParameters();
   var pipesList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
       pipesList.push(results.features[i].geometry);
    }

    lengthParams.polylines = pipesList;
    lengthParams.lengthUnit = GeometryService.UNIT_KILOMETER;
    geometryService.lengths(lengthParams, function (result) {
       var total = 0;
       //summing up each pipe to get the total length of the polygon
       for (var i = 0; i < result.lengths.length; i++) {
           total += result.lengths[i];
       }
       alert(total);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the geometry service, either on your server (it may need to be turned on) or the free esri online one. First, do an intersection of pipes polylines by parcel polygon to get an array of polylines. Then, pass the array to the lengths method to get the total length of the polylines.

See this help page https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html

intersect(geometries,geometry,callback?,errback?)
lengths(lengthsParameter,callback?,errback?)